# Old token for Microsoft Computer Vision API

Tags: api, azure, vision

I generated my token for the API before 5 months. Since then I didn't have any problem using it. Now I see that the whole thing has gone to Azure and I would want to ask if there is any trouble for my token and do I need to make Azure account and buy new token again?